# Cómo puedo meter margen en la izquierda de la página entera?

Tags: html, css

Pongamos de ejemplo la página de youtube.com
Cómo puedo hacer para mover la página entera 30px a la derecha para dejar un margen de 30px a la izquierda, sin que las cosas de la derecha queden fuera de lugar.

Esto es lo que quiero hacer:
[image: Margen en youtube.com]

He probado algo como meterle en el body position:relative y margin-left:30px pero no se mueve toda la página, el sidebar de la izquierda queda intacta, además la parte del topbar de la derecha, donde dice Iniciar Sesión se desplaza y queda fuera de lugar:
[image: Youtube margin 2]

[image: Youtube margin 3]

Puse la página de Youtube como ejemplo, realmente estoy haciendo una cosa en la que tendría esos 30px de espacio reservado en todas las páginas.
Alguna idea? Mil gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Hola! Te doy la bienvenida, por favor revisa [ask]. Para poder brindarte ayuda necesitamos ver un [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con con el siguiente estilo css:

```
body {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

Ó

```
html {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

modifica los **rem** segun el margen que quieras

Comment: Eso no hace nada, ni con position:relative :/